# how to move canvas along with a centered canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas, center

So I have 2 canvases - one big and one small that is on the big one.
My question is how is the easiest and better way to center the big canvas and move the small one with him so that it can be again in the left upper corner as before i center the main canvas.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="projectGame" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
    <canvas id="popUp" width="150" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas-container {
      position: relative;
}
#projectGame {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
       margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
       z-index: 3;
}

#popUp {
      position: absolute;
       z-index: 4;
      border: 5px solid #000000;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put the width and height on the container:

```
#canvas-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 800px;
      height: 800px;
}

<div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="projectGame"></canvas>
    <canvas id="popUp" width="150" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

then make the main canvas 100% of the container:

```
#projectGame {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
       margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
       z-index: 3;
}
```

Then set the popup's top-left where you want it relativly:

```
#popUp {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    z-index: 4;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
}
```

Now move the whole container when you want to move/center/whatever the canvases instead of just moving/centering the one canvas.